# Cannot create tag in git repository

Tags: git

I have a local git repository and I'm working in a given branch (release/0.5.0)

```
$ git status
# On branch release/0.5.0
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

which last commit (HEAD) is

```
$ git log -n 1
commit b24830d8e4df3d3d2553e0422c411fc00d30fe35
Author: foo <foo@bar.com>
Date:   Thu Feb 26 17:55:35 2015 +0100

    ADD Step: 0.4.1-next -> 0.5.0
```

and I have a tag named 0.5.0 (among others)

```
$ git tag
0.4.1/KO
0.5.0
```

which points to the aforementioned last commit in my branch

```
$ git rev-list 0.5.0 | head -n 1
b24830d8e4df3d3d2553e0422c411fc00d30fe35
```

I would like to create a second tag with name 0.5.0/KO pointing to the same commit (I'm assuming that git hasn't problems in having N tags pointing to the same commit). However, I get an error:

```
$ git tag 0.5.0/KO
error: unable to resolve reference refs/tags/0.5.0/KO: Not a directory
fatal: refs/tags/0.5.0/KO: cannot lock the ref
```

Maybe this is due to the name of the new tag stars with the name of an existing tag (the one named 0.5.0) plus "/"? Any help on how could I do this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`refs/tags/0.5.0` already exists, but it is not a directory (it's a file), so Git can't create anything underneath it in the file tree, nor can Git create a directory named `refs/tags/0.5.0`. You'll have to name your new tag something that doesn't include `/` (such as `0.5.0-KO`).

Answer (score 0):

For the record, you can get the same error message on Windows using a samba share.

That is why Git 2.37.3 (Q3 2022) fixes `lstat()` emulation on Windows, to mitigate that.

See [commit 82ba119](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82ba1191ffeaf1482fce9fd9e72334c8dbc3bbbe) (29 Jul 2022) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6c5fbd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c5fbd866c89d939d6202a2594658234d4cf1e90), 08 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`lstat(mingw)`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82ba1191ffeaf1482fce9fd9e72334c8dbc3bbbe): correctly detect ENOTDIR scenarios
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Pierre Garnier</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> Files' attributes can indicate more than just whether they are files or directories.
> It was reported in Git for Windows that on certain network shares, this led to a nasty problem trying to create tags:
>
> ```
> $ git tag -a -m "automatic tag creation"  test_dir/test_tag
> fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/test_dir/test_tag': unable to resolve reference 'refs/tags/test_dir/test_tag': Not a directory
> ```
>
> Note: This does not necessarily happen with all types of network shares.
> One setup where it *did* happen is a Windows Server 2019 VM, and as hinted in
>
> ```
> http://woshub.com/slow-network-shared-folder-refresh-windows-server/
> ```
>
> in the indicated instance the following commands worked around the bug:
>
> ```
> Set-SmbClientConfiguration -DirectoryCacheLifetime 0
> Set-SmbClientConfiguration -FileInfoCacheLifetime 0
> Set-SmbClientConfiguration -FileNotFoundCacheLifetime 0
> ```
>
> This would impact performance negatively, though, as it essentially turns off all caching, therefore we do not want to require users to do that just to be able to use Git on Windows.
>
> The underlying bug is in the code added in [4b0abd5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b0abd5c695c87bf600e57b6a5c7d6844707d34c) ("`mingw`: let lstat() fail with errno == ENOTDIR when appropriate", 2016-01-26, Git v2.8.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f60ccdd98c3f1183922b43478b629049408849ff) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63438327976c8dfbb3b03bcb6b143747afa7e724)) that emulates the POSIX behavior where `lstat()` should return `ENOENT` if the file or directory simply does not exist but could be created, and `ENOTDIR` if there is no file or directory nor could there be because a leading path already exists and is not a directory.
>
> In that code, the return value of `GetFileAttributesW()` is interpreted as an enum value, not as a bit field, so that a perfectly fine leading directory can be misdetected as "not a directory".
>
> As a consequence, the `read_refs_internal()` function would return `ENOTDIR`, suggesting not only that the tag in the [`git tag`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/82ba1191ffeaf1482fce9fd9e72334c8dbc3bbbe/Documentation/git-tag.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag))</sup> invocation above does not exist, but that it cannot even be created.
>
> Let's fix the code so that it interprets the return value of the `GetFileAttributesW()` call correctly.
>
> This fixes [Git For Windows issue 3727](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3727).